# How to take n rows of data from a table referring data from a column in the same table? (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with many data and a sample is as follows

| product_table | data | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | data6 | data7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product id | 001 | 002 | 003 | 004 | 005 | 006 | 007 |
| product name | a | b | c | d | e | f | g |
| status | available | not available | damaged | available | available | not available | damaged |
| order id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 |

I need to extract 2 order ids from each of the statuses from one query.

The out put I want is as follows

| status | order id |
| --- | --- |
| available | 1 |
| available | 4 |
| not available | 2 |
| not available | 6 |
| damaged | 3 |
| damaged | 7 |

I tried using "Limit" but it only brings out the first few data which is in the table.

Query I used

`Select order id , status`
`from table product_table`
`limit 2`
`;`

output I got was

| status | order id |
| --- | --- |
| available | 1 |
| not available | 2 |

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please provide data with columns as columns and rows as rows

Comment: If you don't want the first values you can sort by `column_name desc` and limit will return the values with the highest values. If you don't want the lowest value just put `where not min(column_name)` perhaps with `over (partition by date)` ?

Comment: Notice that you're associating 1->available, 2->not available, 3->damaged, 4->available, (where is 5->?), 6-> not available and 7->damaged. How can you decide to assign `order_id` n to `status` x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition the database by status and use row_number to extract two records.

```
    select status, order_id from (
     select status, order_id, row_number() over (partition by status) as rn from product_table) 
where rn <=2;
```